# PHP Laravel break foreach loop 2 times

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

There are three foreach loop and on the last foreach loop there is an if condition,

```
foreach ($candidate_data as $cd) {
        $edu_data=DB::table('applicant_edu_info')
        ->where('applicant_id',$cd->ap_id)
        ->get();
            foreach($edu_data as $ed){
                foreach($neededDegree as $nd){
                    if($neededDegree->edu_degree_id==$ed->edu_degree_id){
                        $education_data[$cd->ap_id]=$neededDegree->name;

                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

what I need is , If the condition is true then I want to break two loops and continue running from the first foreach loop. Please help.

Comment: You should find a way to simplify your nested loops. Querying every loop is such a waste of memory. Why not do an IN statement instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PHP you can use the optional param of break.

**Use `break 2;`**

```
foreach ($candidate_data as $cd) {
        $edu_data=DB::table('applicant_edu_info')
        ->where('applicant_id',$cd->ap_id)
        ->get();
            foreach($edu_data as $ed){
                foreach($neededDegree as $nd){
                    if($neededDegree->edu_degree_id==$ed->edu_degree_id){
                        $education_data[$cd->ap_id]=$neededDegree->name;
                         break 2;

                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

`break 2` will break two loops.

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [goto](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) which used to jump to another `section` in the program.

```
foreach ($candidate_data as $cd) {
    $edu_data=DB::table('applicant_edu_info')
    ->where('applicant_id',$cd->ap_id)
    ->get();
        foreach($edu_data as $ed){
            foreach($neededDegree as $nd){
                if($neededDegree->edu_degree_id==$ed->edu_degree_id){
                    $education_data[$cd->ap_id]=$neededDegree->name;
                    goto targetLocation;

                }
            }
        }
      targetLocation:
}
```

Using `goto` you can set your `target` anywhere you want.

Comment: that one is pretty good one but in case of specific location it may help too